# How to send GRecaptcha V3 to WP Rest API using Nuxt js

Tags: php, wordpress, vue.js, nuxt.js, recaptcha-v3

i want to send the Google Recaptcha V3 to WP Rest API using Contact Form 7.
This is what i have done so far:

I just use WP as BackEnd API provider, my frontend is in Nuxt app - full static generated code

**Wordpress**

- Install Contact Form 7 plugin
- Configured the Google Recaptcha V3 Site Key and Private Key
- Create a specific form form my Nuxt App
- Test the form in a Wordpress test page and it works fine

**Nuxt**
Install @nuxtjs/recaptcha
Insert in .env the site key and api URL of contact form

*in nuxt.config.js*

```
publicRuntimeConfig: {
    contactFormApi: process.env.CONTACT_FORM_API,
    // other staff
},

modules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/recaptcha', {
        hideBadge: true
        ,siteKey: process.env.RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY
        ,version: 3
      }],
// other staff
],
```

*in layout/default.vue:*

```
async mounted() {
    try {
      await this.$recaptcha.init()
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  },

beforeDestroy () {
    this.$recaptcha.destroy();
   // other staff
  }
```

*contact form component:*

```
<template>
    <form role="form">
        <v-text-field v-model="email" name="email" :label="$t('form.yourEmail')" autocomplete="email" :placeholder="$t('form.yourEmailHint')" clearable
        ></v-text-field>
        <v-textarea v-model="message" name="message" :label="$t('form.yourMessage')" rows="3" value="" :hint="$t('form.yourMessageHint')" clearable
        ></v-textarea>
        <v-checkbox v-model="acceptPrivacy" :label="$t('form.acceptPrivacyTerms')"></v-checkbox>
        <v-btn @click="submit">{{ $t('btns.send') }}</v-btn>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    data: () => ({
        email: '',
        message: '',
        acceptPrivacy: false,
    }),


    methods: {
        async submit() {
            if (!this.acceptPrivacy || this.email == '' || this.message == '') {
                return false;
            }

            try {
                const token = await this.$recaptcha.execute('login');
                console.log('ReCaptcha token:', token);

                const emailBody = {
                    "_wpcf7_recaptcha_response" : token,
                    "wpcf7_recaptcha_response" : token,
                    "recaptcha_response" : token,
                    "recaptcha" : token,
                    "token" : token,

                    "email": this.email,
                    "message" : this.message,
                    "privacy_terms" : this.acceptPrivacy? 1 : 0
                };


                const form = new FormData();
                for (const field in emailBody) {
                    form.append(field, emailBody[field]);
                };

                
                const headers = {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                };

                const data = await this.$axios.$post( 
                        this.$config.contactFormApi, 
                        form, 
                        { headers: headers }
                );

                if (data == null || data == undefined || data.status !== 'spam') {
                    console.log('Email has NOT been sent');
                    console.log(data);
                    return;
                }
                console.log('Email has been sent');
                console.log(data);

            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Login error:', error)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
</script>
```

I try to send the email from my localhost:3000, the other API of WP in order to get pages, post, customPostTypes work as expected.
After every request to WPCF7 i get this response:

```
{
  "into": "#",
  "status": "spam",
  "message": "There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.",
  "posted_data_hash": ""
}
```

As you can see in the request i don't know the proper way to send the gRecaptcha token that i correctly get from google service response:

```
"_wpcf7_recaptcha_response" : token,
"wpcf7_recaptcha_response" : token,
"recaptcha_response" : token,
"recaptcha" : token,
"token" : token,
```

Can you help me for this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, I am having the same problem. I have no idea what endpoint is being used by WP CF7 for the recaptcha token.